# Choose angular template by variable

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have 3 different `<ng-template>`s. My component holds the switching variable with the name of template I want to render. How to inject it into my page?

Comment: You need to share some code.

Comment: I think ou should consider a simple `*ngSwitchCase` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way of course from the following code you have to replace `<div>` with your `<ng-template>`

```
<div [ngSwitch]="yourValue">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'hello'">hello</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'world'">world</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>default</div>
</div>
```

This is the : [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qidnuq)

**UPDATE:** working link corrected.

Comment: This is the better approach.

Comment: Better approach, but example does not work correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to hold references to the templates, and then just refer to that object's property by the string value.

```js
@Component({
   template: `
   <ng-container *ngIf="{One:One,Two:Two,Three:Three} as templates">
       <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templates[name]"></ng-container>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-template #One>ONE</ng-template>
   <ng-template #Two>TWO</ng-template>
   <ng-template #Three>THREE</ng-template>
   `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
   public name = 'One';
}
```